# I can't upload updated version of the app on Testflight

Tags: ios, permissions, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

Let me describe my issue in time perspective:

- I got invited to `AppStoreConnect` team to my e-mail. This e-mail has never been in Apple system before;
- I accepted an invite and received Admin rights;
- This account already has an application in place and I want to upload it's new version on Testflight for others to test it;
- So I logged in to this account in my XCode through `Account` page. Login was successful. Side question - I believe once you get invited to some AppStoreConnect team, Apple ID is created automatically for you, right?
- I put our application Bundle identifier in `Signing & Capabilities` and that's where I start to see 2 errors:

  - `Failed to register bundle identifier. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again`
  - `No profiles for BUNDLE_ID were found.`

**EXPECTATION:** I thought once I get enrolled into AppStoreConnect team with full rights, I will get access to all bundle ids that my team has and I will be able to work with applications using their true bundle identifiers

**REALITY:** It seems that automatically generated Development and Distribution provision profiles and certificates know absolutely nothing about any application our account has. Basically - if I take any other Apple ID account and use it with our app, I will encounter the same issues.

Please fill the gaps in my understanding - what do I need to do to make apps from our account visible for me.

**NOTE:** I emphasize - it is important for me to operate as an owner of the app because I want to upload it to Testflight. So changing bundle id to unique string is not what I am looking for

Comment: If you have selected "Automatic signing" in Xcode, make sure you have selected the correct team in the drop down.  You may also need to obtain a signing certificate

Comment: @Paulw11 Automatic signing is chosen, correct Team is selected meaning my account. But it still doesn't work like there is zero connection of my account with our AppStore and I can't run the app using it's correct bundle identifier.

How can I obtain this signing certificate?

Comment: The team won't be your account. It should be something like `abcd1346wxyz-Acme Corp` - the organisational team. You can issue a developer certificate by logging into developer.Apple.com

Comment: @Paulw11 can I login to developer.apple.com using my account or should I do it with root account only?

Comment: Go to App Store Connect and check if all boxes regarding profiles and ids are checked.

Answer (score 1):

In App Store Connect go to "Users and Access" and check all boxes for Identifiers & Profiles including the ones for certificates.
[image]

Comment: Hello @Yedy, thank you for your response. You mean an owner of root account (root meaning the account that owns AppStoreConnect) should go and check those boxes, correct?

Comment: Hi Eugene, you can log in with your own account into App Store Connect. As an admin you should be able to check these boxes.

Comment: Hi @Yedy! I do not have these checkboxes nor does admin account, I have checked. To be honest, it's the first time I see this UI... Although I didn't work with Appstoreconnect for a long time now. What I do have - I have all permissions possible and I have a permission to "Create apps" and "Upload builds"

Comment: Hm, thats strange. Sounds like maybe you are not in an organization account? Check if the correct team is chosen for signing in Xcode and if so, check in App Store Connect or in Apple Developer for this account if you can find your bundleID there. And check for spelling - maybe copy and paste the bundleID into Xcode.

Comment: Hello @Yedy! Yes, you are correct. It's not an organization account. Thank you for helping me to get this issue sorted